# Не подтягиваются css стили после перенаправления через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть один index.php ,и url вида http://domains.ru/city/stock .  Нужно чтобы , при входе на сайт через подобный url (после доменного имени может быть только 1 или 2 параметра, имена параметров - любые) юзер попадал на index.php ,который находится в корне сайта.
Сделано было так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$     css/$1.css [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$             index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Вводим http://domains.ru/city/stock и получаю index.php без стилей
а в консоли вижу ошибку:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:   "http://domains.ru/city/css/style.css".
```

Подскажите плиз как исправить это?

Comment: Зачем вам эта `RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$     css/$1.css [L,QSA]` строка? Она же перенаправляет на тот же самый адрес, который был вызван. Да еще и не существующие файлы (предыдущие `RewriteCond` как раз к этому перенаправлению относятся, а не ко второму `RewriteRule`).

Comment: я надеялся что эта строка подгрузит стили. Даже если я эту строку уберу, то index.php все равно загружается без стилей

Comment: Вы в вопросе указываете протокол `https` у сайта.  У вас стили так же по протоколу `https` загружаются?

Comment: протокол указан по ошибке, я пока тестирую сайт локально, используя openserver

Comment: Стили же у вас не тут лежат `http://domains.ru/city/css/style.css`, а тут `http://domains.ru/css/style.css`? Если да, то пропишите в шаблонах не относительный путь до стилей, а абсолютный.

Comment: А нет какого- то другого решения? Просто в верстке( а это без малого около 3000 строк) все пути к картинкам/видео прописаны относительными путями и  изображения в каталог выведены  тоже с относительными путями.

Comment: И кстати почему он убирает второй параметр - stock из url , пусть бы заменил оба параметра )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы хотите оставить относительные пути до стилей, то пробуйте такие правила:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /css/([^\/]+).css$ css/$1.css [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: норм, стили подтягивает :) вот только изображения и шрифты при верстке  тоже указывались в относительных путях :(
Подскажите почему, если я после доменного имени указываю только один параметр ,например: http://domains.ru/city , то все отлично загружается, а вот если два параметра, например: http://domains.ru/city/stock , то ничего не грузит? (

Comment: Не используйте относительные пути, на то они и относительные. Вот ответ на все ваши проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите это условие

```
 RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$     css/$1.css [L,QSA]
```

В шаблоне указывайте прямой путь до css. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">`

Comment: сайт полностью рабочий и все стили прописаны в шаблоне. Указанную строку правила я убрал , но проблему это не решило.

Comment: Открывая страницу http://domains.ru/city/stock браузер считает что он находится именно там, неважно что за скрипт реально обрабатывает. Если стиль прописан как css/style.css то искать он его будет на http://domains.ru/city/stock/css/style.css а не там где он физически находится. Поэтому в случае всяких ЧПУ указывайте абсолютные пути.